# Is Grapher (Apple)scriptable, and if so, how?

Tags: mac, applescript

I use Grapher all the time, and while I think it's mostly wonderful, there are some things about it that I find annoying.  Specifically:

- The default 2D graph has annoying
  default options that require many
  clicks to change to the settings I
  prefer.
- If I edit the color or line
  size of a graph and then change the
  equation generating that graph, I
  lose my style changes and have to
  re-do them.

I think I could manage these (especially the first one) better if Grapher were scriptable via Applescript or Automator; if I could write a script like `Create Better 2D Graph` or something, that'd go a long way to making my life easier.  But I can't find any documentation to help me; I can't even find anything that mentions whether or not it's even possible.  Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The place to look is the Script Editor application, where you can see a list of applications that have AppleScript dictionaries. Grapher doesn't, sadly.

Consider filing a formal feature request with Apple about this... or buy some full-featured math software.